# Which of the following corn dog illustrations look better in term of color and shape?

Tags: illustration

First one = top. Second one = bottom.

[image]

Which one looks better in terms of shape and color? And what are the reasons? (If you ignore the background

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity You are right, I removed the background.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Okay, I made it look happier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Better" **really** depends upon usage and desired impression.

- Due to the lack of color saturation and overall line work, the **Top Dog** looks far more "vintage" and less expressive.
- The **Bottom Dog** looks more "modern" and more expressive (both dogs appear "happy")

The bottom dog gives a *much* clearer sense of *wearing* the corndog costume than the top image does. The top dog could actually *be* the shape of a corndog. Depth of the costume isn't conveyed as well in the top image. However, the catsup seems to merely STOP at the neck without reason in the bottom image.